# Place Play Framework 2.1 database evolutions in sub project?

Tags: database, playframework-2.1

I have a [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) 2.1 application, and the database code is located in a sub project — in case I want to support more than one kind of backend in the future, e.g. a file based database or Cassandra.

Currently, however, the database is a relational database and I'd like to use [Play's database evolutions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Evolutions) mechanism. But I don't know how, or if it is even possible, to place the evolutions script in my sub project (where they belong), rather than in the main project. — If I place them in the sup project, Play apparently ignores them.  Question: **Can I place my evolutions script in my sub project, and how do I do it?**

*Edit* October 2015:  I use [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/) now instead of Play's built-in evolutions, since a year or so. I heartily recommend FlywayDB. You can do evolutions in your sub projects with FlywayDB in any way you want, and you need to write the code that starts the evolutions yourself. */Edit*

---

This is what I've tried thus far:

1. Create a sub project, `./modules/evolutions-test/`
2. In that sub project, create an evolutions script:
        `./modules/evolutions-test/conf/evolutions/default/1.sql`
3. Don't configure database connection info in the sub project — apparently,
    those settings are ignored (?). Configure the connection info in the main
    project config file instead, e.g.:

   ```
   db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
   db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.123/test_evolutions"
   db.default.user=test_evolutions
   db.default.password=...
   ```
4. Include JDBC and the PostgreSQL driver as dependencies of the sub project.
5. Have my main project depend on the sub project.
   <sub>(And hit `reload` in Play's console.)</sub>

This didn't make Play realize that there is an evolutions script to apply in the sub project. Instead, Play finds and uses any evolutions script that is located in the *main* projects `conf` directory. So I suppose I could softlink from the main project to the sub project, and in that manner still keep the contents of the evolution scripts in the sub project.

<sub>(I've answered my own question below, because I might as well post all this now once I've written this question — and it actually ought to be useful to some other people? Shouldn't somewhat many people consider placing database code in a sub module?)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently not possible? See:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/548JUZnjStE/x1hbXyc7PQwJ
which is a discussion about how this can be "fixed" somehow.

Instead, I could softlink from
`<main-project>/conf/evolutions/default`
to
`<main-project>/modules/evolutions-test-project/conf/evolutions/default`